# Checking when a selection of files have changed

Tags: git

Ok, so I am on git.  I notice the layout of my web page is all over the place. The project has a bunch of `*.css` files (about 8 in total in different locations of the same repo).  I would like to check all commits to these files for the branch I am on - over the last two weeks,

Is this possible?

I know for a single file I could do:

```
git log -p ./reports/my.css
```

What is the best way to do it for all css files in different directories. The best I got so far is to do something like:

```
git log --since=2.weeks --name-status | grep -B 8 "css"
```

i.e. I grep the log from the last 2 weeks and then I pull out the 8 lines before to make sure I get file and commit info.

Thanks.

Comment: Just list all of them. You might have luck using `'*.css'` (note the quotes)

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to another answer that mentioned that `git log` does indeed take multiple file arguments and can show a log of all commits that have touched those files.

If you wish to discover all *.css files when invoking this command in one step, then use the following `find` invocation:

`find . -iname '*.css' -exec git log --since=2.weeks --name-status  {} +`

In plain english, this command finds all files ending with .css, ignoring case, in the current working directory and all subdirectories and executes `git log --since=2.weeks --name-status` passing all of the file names it found as arguments.

Comment: super. Just wondering could you explain what the {} and + mean in the statement?

Comment: From the find man page... `-exec command {} +
This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files. The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines. Only one instance of '{}' is allowed within the command. The command is executed in the starting directory.`

Answer (score 1):

`git log` can receive a list of file, so just give all of the relevant files as arguments:

```
git log -p ./reports/my.css ./anotherdir/his.css ./thirddir/their.css
```